# Difference between port-channel lacp fallback individual VS. static?

Tags: network, port-channel, arista

What is the exact difference between:

- port-channel lacp fallback individual
- port-channel lacp fallback static

Comment: For which device model?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From this [ARISTA manual](https://www.arista.com/assets/data/pdf/user-manual/um-eos/Chapters/Port%20Channels%20and%20LACP.pdf), page 620:

> **Static fallback**: the port channel maintains one active port while in
> fallback mode; all its other memberports are in standby mode until a
> LACP PDU is received by the port channel. All member ports send(and
> can receive) LACP PDUs, but only the active port sends or receives
> data.
>
> **Individual fallback**: all member ports act as individual switch
> ports while in fallback mode. Individualport configuration (rather
> than port channel configuration) is active while the port channel is
> in fallbackmode, with the exception of ACLs. This includes VLAN
> membership. All member ports send andreceive data, and continue to
> send LACP PDUs. As soon as a LACP PDU is received by a member ofthe
> port channel, all ports revert to normal port-channel operation.